# where can I find the 'Clicks' metric group in Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I believe there is a 'Clicks' metric group in Google Analytics, however I cannot find it and there is little to no documentation on this.

Does this still exist in GA and, if so, what report shall I find it in?

Comment: Are you referring to [AdWords campaign clicks](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/adwords?hl=en#ga:adClicks) or [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) for click events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AdWords Campaigns and Keyword reports include a Clicks metric group, which displays a range of cost- and click-related AdWords metrics such as clickthrough rate (CTR) and cost per click (CPC).